# Install Ubuntu, eth0 not detected?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, toshiba-laptop, ifconfig, network-interface

I have installed Ubuntu laptop Toshiba Satellite L640?, and I had difficulty, that is how to enable network interfaces, eth0 was not detected when running ifconfig.

Comment: What does `cat /etc/network/interfaces` show? Please [edit] and add that to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the driver is not installed, so you have to find out the driver and load the related kernel module ... Exec this command to find out the network card you have installed :

```
lspci | grep -i eth
```

Comment: I don't know too, but there are no interfaces were detected after installing Ubuntu 10.04, only lo, it is difficult for me in doing the update repository
okay I will try this command, thank you

Comment: so what does the output of "lspci | grep -i eth" give you? (we already know that no interfaces were properly detected; nevertheless the lspci command might give you some hints on which interfaces are actually installed - so you (might) know which driver you have to manually install to get your interface be properly enabled)